# Drawing PV solar Profile with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a simple graph as below using tikz (or another package)?

[image: PV rooftop system]

Comment: If you have the data/functions, plot it with `pgfplots`.

Comment: Of course you can, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just because it looked like a fun thing to make. I haven't added any explanatory comments. If you don't understand all the code after studying it and using the `pgfplots` manual as a reference, you can always ask.  But please do try to work through it (and other examples in the manual or on the site for that matter). If you get even a basic understanding of how `pgfplots` work, then the next time you need to make some plot, you'll be able to do most of the work yourself, and you need only ask about the more finicky stuff. So instead of just posting an image and saying "how do I do this" (which is what gets you the downvotes, though not from me), you can post some code and ask about the specific thing you were unable to do.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\sansmath]
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines*=left,
  xlabel=Time of day,
  ylabel=Production/consumption (kW),
  xmin=0,xmax=24,
  ymin=0,ymax=12,
  domain=0:24,
  samples=96,
  xtick distance=4,
  xticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt<10pt0\fi\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}:00},
  legend style={
    draw=none,
    nodes={right, font=\small\sffamily}
  }
]


\addlegendimage{black!30,fill, area legend}
\addlegendimage{black!50,fill, area legend}
\addlegendimage{black!60,fill, area legend}

\addplot [draw=black, fill=black, fill opacity=0.5] {(x-12)^2/32 + rnd*3*rnd + 1} \closedcycle;
\addplot [draw=black, fill=black, fill opacity=0.3] {exp(-(x-12)^2/20)*3.5}       \closedcycle;


\legend{Surplus PV Production, Surplus consumption, Self-consumption}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```